# 4D Framework worth it or not?

Tags: migration, 4d-database

I was asked at work to participate in a new project:
Migration from old version to the newest version of Framework 4D.
I really don't know what is 4D Framework is.

My question is: Does it really worth it to learn 4D framework and to participate in the migration of it ?

Luckily I have the right to reject the proposal if I'm not interested.

regards,

Comment: This is not the right place for your question

Comment: could you please tell me the right place ?

Answer (score 1):

I'm going to agree with @Avra that this isn't really the right kind of question for SO. But I'll answer it with a little bit of my experience.

4D is a rapid application development environment. It lets you quickly build a database-backed application with a UI created with drag-and-drop UI elements. It is good at designing "simple" business applications. Mostly the kind of thing that a small- or medium-sized business might use internally to handle parts of their business process.

It is still a going concern and is being actively developed.

I write 4D all day. I don't like it. Even after 6 years the names of commands are still so inconsistent and non-obvious to me that I have to look it them up regularly. The UI builder is quite good, but the moment you want to do something it doesn't support it gets hard fast.  There isn't any integration with version control at all (everything lives in the binary project file). The web server is sort of clunky (it has a built-in web server). The licensing is confusing (for me at least). The online documentation is frequently down. The dev community is small so finding answers can be difficult.

I would never build something new in it, but if it is currently working for the customer, you can learn enough 4D to keep it going rather quickly. You'll need to buy licenses from 4D to cover whatever features and deployment types your customer wants to use.

Comment: Anecdotal, though you might be interested @JoshuaHunter, we've been developing a fairly large suite of fintech applications using 4D, and while you are bang on with it's failings, you can build quite large business applications in it if you don't rely on the GUI :)

Comment: @AaronLavers, we build a large OEM application in 4D. It is doable, but I wouldn't start a new project in it. Maybe a one-off application for a small or medium business to cover a specific and not too complex business need (as an alternative to MS Access), but nothing else.